# Is making a user confirm a UIActionSheet action bad design?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiactionsheet

I'm using a `UIActionSheet` to let the user choose one of multiple actions. One of these actions is "Delete". However, the user might hit delete by mistake.

Should I reconsider having the action "Delete" mixed with other actions in this list, or is there some way I could make the user confirm that the choice was correct? For example a new `UIActionSheet` with the question "Are you sure you want to delete? Yes/No", or would this be considered as bad design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd consider having the delete action as a separate button, and then having the Action sheet as the confirmation.

If you take the Photos app as an example, the delete action is not in the action menu, but it's own button which then asks for confirmation using an action sheet. This is the same with other apps, like iMovie and Pages.

The user probably won't like having to press through 2 action sheets, but will be even more annoyed if they accidentally press it. You can help with preventing accidents by making the delete option red in the action sheet, if you haven't already.

It also depends on what is being deleted, if you are wiping the phone in the settings menu, then you will be asked twice. But deleting something like text is not going to have confirmation at all.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what he deletes is critical or not.
If it's critical, you should definitively have the user re-confirm.

Tell me one OS where formatting the Hard Disk for example doesn't ask you to reconfirm... :-)

Comment: Haha, I definitely agree with you. I don't want the user to be able to delete without confirmation, so my question was if it'd be wrong to make one UIActionSheet confirm the action of another, or if I should have a separate delete button, or if there is any another way to do it